# Knockout validation Issuue

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

```
function ProductViewModel()
{
var self = this;

self.Amount= ko.observable(0);

self.Quantity= ko.observable(0);
}

ko.extenders.numeric = function(target, precision) {
var result = ko.computed({
    read: target,  
    write: function(newValue) {
      var value = parseFloat(newValue,10);
      if(precision > 0){
        target(value.toFixed(precision));
      }
      else{
        target(Math.round(value));
      }
    }
});

result(target());

return result;
};

ko.applyBindings(new ProductViewModel());
```

Now i want to add extenders dynamically after observable is created not at a time of declaration ?
I also fetching data from server and converting to observable using ko.mapping.fromJS(data) and after that i want to add extenders...so guide me guys....

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that your defined extender isn't working? It looks like you are missing a call to `ko.validation.registerExtenders();`

Put the above line just before you call applyBindings

Comment: Sorry i don't know how **ko.validation.registerExtenders()** thing works.Can you suggest something ?

Comment: just add that line to your js under where you have the rules defined

Comment: I'll use this and keep u posted if i need any help.Thanks tom.